# Why does `struct sockaddr` contain a address family field?

Tags: c, sockets, unix

Why does `struct sockaddr` contain an address family field? Isn't the address family already fixed with the call to `socket()`?

Comment: My guess is that the kernel just routes the call based on the family provided in bind. I suppose each family would correspond to a different kernel module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sockaddr` is used in more places than just `connect` and `bind`, including places where you don't have some external knowledge of the address family involved - `getaddrinfo` being one.

Additionally, whilst I don't believe the following equates to practice anywhere, I can see it having been in the eye of whoever designed this stuff originally: the call to `socket()` defines the protocol family.  `sockaddr` contains the address family.  In practice, I believe these are always the same, but you could theoretically have a protocol capable of supporting two different address types.

EDIT: There's another way that the parameter is useful.  If you're using datagram (UDP) sockets and you have a socket in a "connected" state with a default destination address, you can [clear out that address](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_343.html) by calling `connect()` with a `sockaddr` with `sa_family` set to `AF_UNSPEC`.

Comment: Hmm... +1 for "more places" and the PF vs. AF theory, but `struct sockaddr` predates `getaddrinfo` by at least 15 years.

Comment: larsmans, I've added a place that uses the parameter and where the methods in question have been around as long as `struct sockaddr`.  I don't know if that specific functionality has been around that long, though.  Other than that one place, I don't know of anything else that would really need the family and which has been around as long as `struct sockaddr` has.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the `getaddrinfo` interface, which is the only modern correct way to convert between interchange representations of addresses (names or numeric addresses) and the `sockaddr` structures, I think you'll see why it's needed.

With that said, the whole `struct sockaddr` stuff is a huge mess of misdesigns, especially the userspace endian conversion.

Another good instance of why the `sa_family` field is needed is the `getsockname` and `getpeername` interfaces. If the program inherited the file descriptor from another program, and doesn't already know what type of socket it is, it needs to be able to determine that in order to make new connections or even convert the address to a representation suitable for interchange.

Comment: @R: this is also important for dual-stack IPv4/IPv6 server sockets to detect whether an IPv4 or IPv6 client connected.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the network code for [4.2BSD](http://unixarchive.cn-k.de/4BSD/Distributions/4.2BSD/), where the sockets interface originated, you'll see that the `sockaddr` is passed to the network interface drivers but the socket fd is not.

Answer (score 0):

The sa_family field is used to tell what type of address will be in the sa_data field.  In a lot of applications, the address family is assumed to be IPV4.  However, many applications also support IPV6.

Comment: But even for IPv6 the address family is already set in the call to socket(), isn't it?